# Publish .Net Core to IIS - Process cannot access file

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am deploying my ASP .Net Core 2.0 app to my remote server using FTP. Remote Server is using IIS 8. When I publish my app, I get the following error.

```
Unable to add 'Project.dll' to the Web site.  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process (550).
```

I been able to bypass this by manually creating an `app_offline.htm` first on the publish directory, and then publishing my app via Visual Studio 2017.

I was wondering, is there an easier way of doing this? or is there an easy way I can script this, so that app_offline gets created automatically before publish? and then deleted after publish?

Comment: What functionality did you do? are you opening a file by using your project? make sure that you disposed the object.

Comment: Hmm... Interesting point. No, there was no file open/close. I believe this happens to all asp core projects via ftp. When I Google, it seems to be common issue, however, I just did not find a proper solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone that's curious, I gave up depending on VS to publish my .NET Core project. I'm now using **[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php)** and _PublishToWeb.bat script I created to accomplish the task.

I first created a file called `_app.offline.htm` on root directory my publish folder. Then when I need to publish, I run the script below.

This script does the following:
 1. Builds the .NET Core project to a specific folder, let's call it "_dist" folder.
 2. Connects to my ftp server/publish folder and renames "_app_offline.html" to "app_offline.html", so that the server goes offline.
 3. Synchronizes _dist folder with publish folder.
 4. When done, changes "app_offline.htm" to "_app_offline.html", so the website is restarted.

**_PublishToWeb.bat**

```
echo off
echo Publishing to ProjectName (Optional)
set ProjectRemoteFolder=RemoteFolderName
set ConnectionString=ftp://username:password@serverIp:serverPort
set WinSCP="path to WinSCP.com"
set ProjectDistPath="a folder where dotnet publish will build the project to"
set WebAppProject="path of the project. dotnet publish will run here"

rem Build project and put it in to distribution folder
cd %WebAppProject%
dotnet publish -c Release -o %ProjectDistPath%

rem Connect to FTP and synchronize folder
%WinSCP% /command "open %ConnectionString%/%ProjectRemoteFolder%/" "mv _app_offline.htm app_offline.htm" "synchronize remote %ProjectDistPath%" "mv app_offline.htm _app_offline.htm" "exit"

rem pause
```

I'm sure there are better solutions out there, but this has been working well for me so far.

Comment: Great solution, Visual Studio publish to ftp was not working at all for us.. Thank you!

Comment: This workaround about .bat is inconvenient because someone needs to copy minified ccs, js, assets and other things.

Comment: @LapenkovVladimir minified css, js, etc. Should be done during build time and should be in the distribution folder. If not, you can modify the .bat file to copy minified css, js, etc. files from other locations before performing the sync. This is just one way, please share if you have better alternatives.

Comment: @FerX32, assets and js are by default in wwroot folder, not in distrib folder

Comment: @LapenkovVladimir wwwroot folder is inside dist folder (assuming your publish build was successful). Therefore, those static files inside wwwroot are already designed to sync. I know because I've been using them.